# Go through a list of points and find minimum window size to display them all?

Tags: c

I have a set of 2D points and need to draw various pretty curves between each pair of points. Then I need to display the curves (and the points) on the screen, of course I want to fill as much of the screen space as possible. So the question is how can I find the smallest rectangle which contains all the points?

[image]

So far I have something (quite ugly and unusable) like this:

```
int max_x = 0;    
int max_y = 0;
int min_x = 0;
int min_y = 0;

CurveRenderData* CalculateCurveInfo(Vector2 *p1, Vector2 *p2) 
{
.... // calculate the curve information and store it in CurveRenderData structure

if (max_x < MAX(p1->x, p2->x))
    max_x = MAX(p1->x, p2->x);
if (max_y < MAX(p1->y, p2->y))
    max_y = MAX(p1->y, p2->y);

if (min_x < MIN(p1->x, p2->x)) 
    min_x = MIN(p1->x, p2->x);
if (min_y < MIN(p1->y, p2->y))
    min_y = MIN(p1->y, p2->y);

... // more stuff

return CurveRenderDataPtr;
}
```

Now we have the min_x, min_y, max_x and max_y. So we can easily distribute the points on the screen.

I thought about re factoring the min,max finding functionality out, but that would require two passes over the data (which would be slow).

**So the question:** How can this logic be coded in a better manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (max_x < MAX(p1->x, p2->x))
    max_x = MAX(p1->x, p2->x);
```

I would write:

```
max_x = MAX(max_x, MAX(p1->x, p2->x));
```

Similar for `min_x` using `MIN()`.

The functionality is the same, the code generated by the compiler (after the removal of `max_x = max_x` which is a no-op) is probably the same. And I find it easier to read and understand.

Read it like this: *"put in `max_x` the biggest value from the current value of `max_x` and the biggest of `p1->x` and `p2->x`"*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little cleaner:

```
max_x = MAX(max_x, MAX(p1->x, p2->x));
max_y = MAX(max_y, MAX(p1->y, p2->y));

min_x = MIN(min_x, MIN(p1->x, p2->x));
min_y = MIN(min_y, MIN(p1->y, p2->y));
```

But you still have to run through the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
store first point as min and max
for remaining points:
    min_x = MIN(min_x, point->x);
    max_x = MAX(max_x, point->x);
    min_y = MIN(min_y, point->y);
    max_y = MAX(max_y, point->y);
```